# Difference between `git submodule init && git submodule update` and `git submodule update --init`?

Tags: git

Is there any difference between

`git submodule init && git submodule update --recursive`

and

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

?

*And if so, what is the exact difference?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

**No, there is no difference**. `git submodule init && git submodule update --recursive` and `git submodule update --init --recursive` are functionally identical.

#### Long answer

`git submodule init` registers each submodule in the local Git configuration (in `.git/config`). In there, you can specify the location from where Git should clone the submodules.

This means that you can first use `git submodule init` to register the submodules in your local configuration, then edit `.git/config` to change the default clone source URL for the submodule repositories, and then do a `git submodule update`.

If you do not want to change the submodule source location, you can simply run `git submodule update --init`.

To quote the man page:

> **init**
>     Initialize the submodules, i.e. **register each submodule name and url found in `.gitmodules` into `.git/config`**. [...] You can then customize the submodule clone URLs in `.git/config` for your local setup and
>              proceed to `git submodule update`; **you can also just `use git submodule update --init` without the explicit init step if you do not intend to customize any submodule locations**.